# Problems using bcm2835_v4l2 module w/ ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, v4l2, mmal

I've run into some problems using the native `bcm2835_v4l2` module on my Raspberry Pi Zero W (running Raspbian Stretch).  The module is loaded and the associated video device is visible:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
mmal service 16.1 (platform:bcm2835-v4l2):
    /dev/video0

$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
[...displays all the expected formats...]
```

But when I try to capture from this device, I am getting an error message:

```
$ ffmpeg  -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -framerate 30 -video_size 1024x768 -i /dev/video0 -c copy -t 10 video.mp4
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1053250] ioctl(VIDIOC_STREAMON): Operation not permitted
/dev/video0: Operation not permitted
```

Despite the error message, this doesn't appear to be a permissions issue.  I see the same behavior if I run the `ffmpeg` command as `root`.

There are a number of web pages out there that appear to be running substantially the same command with the error (and remarkably few results when I search for the error message).  What could be going on here?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be code for "you haven't assigned enough memory to the GPU".

Using the `raspivid` command in this situation resulted in:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Only 64M of gpu_mem is configured. Try running "sudo raspi-config" and ensure that "memory_split" has a value of 128 or greater
```

Adding...

```
gpu_mem=128
```

...to `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting has resolved the problem, and `ffmpeg` now works as expected.

Comment: .. to /boot/firmware/config.txt also make sure that start_x=1 is added as well

Answer (score 1):

As an Update, it looks like this needs 256MB now (got the hint from [github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3467#issuecomment-618877099))